# 'System.Collections.Generic.List<int>.Contains(int)' has some invalid arguments

Tags: linq, entity-framework, entity

A Enity framework query shows error don't know why. If i am trying to get list of primary Id's.

```
            int PlantDemandId = 1;
            var result = (from c in context.tbl_PlantSupply
                          where c.DemandId == PlantDemandId
                          select c.Id).ToList();
```

**c.Id is a primary key**

when i am using c.DemandId it is working fine.

when i am using c.Id it shows error on below query.

```
            var result1 = (from c in context.tbl_NoOfPlantSupplied
                           join p in context.PlantationTypes on c.PlantationTypeId equals p.Id
                           join cl in context.Clones on c.CloneId equals cl.Id
                           where result.Contains(c.PlantSupplyId)

                           select new
                           {
                               PlantSupplyId = c.PlantSupplyId,
                               SourceOfSupplyId = c.SourceOfSupplyId,
                               PlantationTypeId = c.PlantSupplyId,
                               PlantationTypeName=p.Name,
                               CloneId = c.CloneId,
                               CloneName=cl.Name,
                               Supply = c.Supply
                           }).ToList();
```

where result.Contains(c.PlantSupplyId) :  this line shows an error

```
    'System.Collections.Generic.List<int>.Contains(int)' has some invalid arguments
     convert from int? to int
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't compare int? and int. Use

```
c.PlantSupplyId.HasValue && result.Contains(c.PlantSupplyId.Value)
```

instead

Comment: its c.PlantSupplyId.Value...  Value's V is  capital (intelligence help not show this).. Thanks Dear :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like PlantSupplyId have null values. Please check tbl_NoOfPlantSupplied whether it has null values. I'm sure it does. That's why the error is asking you to convert nullable int (int?) to int, as you can't pass null in contains() function.

If it's okay to have null values in PlantSupplyId column, then you have handle that in your query by eliminating null valued rows.